# change state individually in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The data is coming dynamically and I want to change state of `bookmark` icon individually. When we click on first box then only change state of `bookmark` of that box only others will remain as it is.

**My code**

```
 this.state={ isTagged: false };

_handle_tag_btn() {
    if(this.state.isTagged == true) {
       this.setState({isTagged: false})
    }
    else {
       this.setState({isTagged: true})
    }
}
render(){
   return(
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        {
           this.state.product_detail.length <= 0 ?
              <ActivityIndicator color = '#bc2b78' size = "large"  />
           :
              <View  style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
                {
                    this.state.product_detail.map((data, index) => (
                        <View style={s.cate_detail_box}>
                           <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.9} style={{height: 190}} onPress={this._goto_individual_detail}>
                              <Image source={{uri: data.images[0].src}} style={s.img}/>
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                          <View style={{padding: 5}}>
                              <View activeOpacity={0.9} style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                                  <View>                     
                                     <CapitalizedText style={s.cate_detail_title}>{data.title}</CapitalizedText>
                                     <Text style={s.cate_detail_price}>{'₹' + data.variants[0].price}</Text>
                                  </View>
                                  <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.7} onPress={this._handle_tag_btn} key={index}>
                                    {                        
                                       this.state.isTagged ? 
                                          <Icon size={icon_size} color="#aaa" name="turned-in-not" />
                                       :
                                          <Icon size={icon_size} color="#aaa" name="turned-in" />
                                    }

                                 </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                      </View>
                  </View>
                 ))
               }
           </View>
        }
    </View>
  );
}
```

**My output** https://i.stack.imgur.com/05uPN.jpg

In this image all bookmarks are selected which is not required.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the bookmark view inside `.map` and create a new component and then toggle the bookmark status in that component. You pass the data attribute as a prop to this new component -

```
class Bookmark extends React.Component {
  state = { isTagged: false }

  _handle_tag_btn() {
    if (this.state.isTagged == true) {
      this.setState({ isTagged: false })
    } else {
      this.setState({ isTagged: true })
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props
    return (
      <View style={s.cate_detail_box}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={0.9}
          style={{ height: 190 }}
          onPress={this._goto_individual_detail}
        >
          <Image source={{ uri: data.images[0].src }} style={s.img} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
          <View
            activeOpacity={0.9}
            style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between" }}
          >
            <View>
              <CapitalizedText style={s.cate_detail_title}>
                {data.title}
              </CapitalizedText>
              <Text style={s.cate_detail_price}>
                {"₹" + data.variants[0].price}
              </Text>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.7}
              onPress={this._handle_tag_btn}
              key={index}
            >
              {this.state.isTagged ? (
                <Icon size={icon_size} color="#aaa" name="turned-in-not" />
              ) : (
                <Icon size={icon_size} color="#aaa" name="turned-in" />
              )}
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

And then use it inside your `.map` like this -

```
this.state.product_detail.map((data, index) => <Bookmark data={data} />)
```

Comment: it is giving an error that `can't find variable: data`.

Comment: i have edited the answer so that it takes data from props. Do you know about props and how props are passed in react?

Comment: yes I know about props and thank you so much you saved my time it is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `tagged` object in `state`, for example:

```
this.state={ taggedObject: null };


_handle_tag_btn(data) {
    if(this.state.taggedObject === data) {
       this.setState({taggedObject: null})
    }
    else {
       this.setState({taggedObject: data})
    }
}

// ... 

<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.7} onPress={() => this._handle_tag_btn(data)} key={index}>
    {                        
       this.state.taggedObject === data ? 
         <Icon size={icon_size} color="#aaa" name="turned-in-not" />:        
         <Icon size={icon_size} color="#aaa" name="turned-in" />
    }                  
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: I tried your answer too but it is not giving any output and just loading and after sometime it gives me an error that `Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded.` When I removed `<TouchableOpacity>` completely this error gone.

Comment: Did you change this too? `onPress={() => this._handle_tag_btn(data)}`

Comment: kiarashws, it is working but when I clicked one product then it will be selected but when I clicked on another then 1st one will removed.

Comment: If you want to have multiple tagged products then you must implement a  `taggedArray` instead of  `taggedObject`